# Vanishing of a global sections space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, positivity

Let $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb P^n_k$ be a projective variety over $k$ of degree $\delta$ with respect to $\mathcal O(1)$, $x\in X(k)$ be a regular rational point (I think a closed point is also OK). Let $\pi:\widetilde X\rightarrow X$ be the blow-up at $x$, and $E$ be the exceptional divisor. Let $H$ be a Cartier divisor over $X$ given by a hyperplane section on $\mathbb P^n_k$. We consider $H^0(\widetilde X, d\pi^*H-mE)$, where $d, m\in\mathbb N$. We fix $d$, then when $m$ is large enough, we have $H^0(\widetilde X, d\pi^*H-mE)=0$.

My question is: can we give a lower bound of $m$ such that for all $m$ larger than it, we will have the above vanishing result? I guess this bound is of $O_{\delta,n}(d)$.

Comment: I started to say any $m$ larger that the maximal possible multiplicity of a degree $d$ hypersurface through $x$ (multiplicity WRT to $X$, not $\mathbb P^n$), but if there are hypersurfaces on $X$ which don't arise by restricting from $\mathbb P^n$ one could possibly have larger $m$. So any bound may depends on some higher cohomology vanishing. Also, is your last sentence meant to refer to asymptotic big-O notation? If so you should probably use the notation $\mathcal O(1)$ in your first sentence to differentiate.

Comment: I have changed my notations. The last sentence uses the Landau notion. Could you give a reference about what you said?

Comment: Not really; this is pretty much just definitional in my mind. A section of $d\pi^* H - mE$ just *is* a hypersurface in $X$ of class $dH$ which has multiplicity $m$ at $x$. I believe that $\pi_* (\mathcal O_{\widetilde{X}}(d\pi^* H - mE)) = \mathcal O_X(dH)\otimes \mathcal I_x^m$, which maybe makes this clearer (and preserves $H^0$).

Comment: If you think it is easier to consider the push forward, you can use it. Of course, they are same in some sense.